# How do I add .each results to a <ul>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, sharepoint, each

I'm iterating through a SharePoint list and the results are passed by in JSON. This is done with .each

Then I'm using an if statement (if a certain column of data equals a certain phrase) add that result to an unordered list on the page.

My issue is it's only adding the last iteration. How can I make sure it's adding every item that matches my if statement?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://site/subsite/project/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('SharePoint List')/items",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index) { 
        var courseName = $(this).attr('Title'); 
        var courseNumber = $(this).attr('Course_x0020_Number'); 
        var active = $(this).attr('Active'); 
        var courseUrl = $(this).attr('URL'); 
        var trainingGroup = $(this).attr('Training_x0020_Group'); 

            if (trainingGroup == 'Lab') {
                document.getElementById('labListSpan').innerHTML = '<ul class="courseLists"><li><input type="checkbox" id="'+courseName.replace(/\s+/g, '')+'"/>'+courseName+'</li></ul>';

            }
        });
        },
        error:  function(){
        alert("Failed to query SharePoint list data. Please refresh (F5).");
        }
    });
}
pullTrainingCourses();
```

Comment: Side note, you are repeatedly doing `$(this)`.  Every time you do that you are creating a new jQuery object, which is relatively expensive.  Create it once, store it in a var, and reuse that var.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to go about this? I'm new to jquery

Comment: storing the $(this)?  that just a `var $this = $(this);` as the first thing in the each, and then just use $this every where that you are currently doing $(this)

Comment: Makes perfect sense - implementing now!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('labListSpan').innerHTML = '<ul class="courseLists"><li><input type="checkbox" id="'+courseName.replace(/\s+/g, '')+'"/>'+courseName+'</li></ul>';
```

You are replacing the innerHTML every time.  Instead of '=' use '+='

Comment: WOW - so simple, yet I was banging my head against the wall here the last half hour. Thank you so much!!